# Is this scenario possible?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus, lotus-formula

Is this scenario possible in one form using button?

**If I create a new record:**
My save & close button will send a notification.

**If I edit existing an existing record:**
My save & close button won't send a notification.

**Currently, I have 4 buttons:**
Edit, Exit, Save & Close.

**When I click new:**
Save & Close button is only shown.

**When I open an existing:**
Edit and Exit is shown. Then when I click Edit, the Save & Close will appear.

**Planning to add another save & close button where I will put this code.
Then will only show when I'm in create new mode but not in edit mode.

```
Sub Click(Source As Button)
    Dim ses As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase 
    Dim doc As NotesDocument 
    Dim body As NotesRichtextItem
    ' get the database
    Set db = ses.CurrentDatabase
    ' create a new document in the database
    Set doc = New NotesDocument( db )
    ' set the new document's form so it'll be readable as a mail memo
    doc.Form = "Memo"
    ' set the new document's subject
    doc.Subject = "Notification"
    ' set the new document's body
    Set body = New NotesRichtextitem( doc, "Body" )
    Call body.AppendText( "A new record has been created." )
    Call body.AddNewLine(1)
    Call body.AppendText( "Click here to open the document --> " )  
    Call body.AppendDocLink( ws.CurrentDocument.document, "Click me" )
    'Call doc.Send( False, "Lekhwair Alatan")
    Dim recipients( 1 To 2 ) As String
    recipients( 1 ) = "recipient 1"
    recipients( 2 ) = "recipient 2"
    Call doc.Send( True, recipients )
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

So I'm assuming this code is in an Action Bar button or another Button on the form in the UI.

So, from the NotesUIWorkspace you can grab the CurrentDocument (type NotesUIDocument) and from that you can check the property IsNewDoc. You might also save as a field on the document the date/time you sent the notification so you can always go back and verify a notification was sent.

```
Dim workspace as New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim docuiCurrent as NotesUIDocument

set docuiCurrent = workspace.CurrentDocument

if docuiCurrent.Document.HasItem( "$UpdatedBy" ) then
    // send notification
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the code for the mail send function in the post save event of your form. Add a new field to save the status.

A simplified version may look like this:

```html
dim mailSent as string
mailSent = doc.getitemvalue("MailSent")(0)
if len(mailSent)=0 then
 call sendMail(doc)
 call doc.replaceItemvalue("MailSent",cstr(now))
 call doc.save(true,false)
end if
```